# PHP arrays + Mustache templates

Tags: php, mustache

In PHP, I’m generating a simple array (list) to provide to the [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io) renderer. The array looks something like this:

```
Top-level Array ( 
    [times] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
                [hour] => 00
                [min] => 00
                [time] => 12am
            )

        [1] => Array (
                [hour] => 00
                [min] => 15
                [time] => 12:15am
            )

        [2] => Array (
                [hour] => 00
                [min] => 30
                [time] => 12:30am
            )
     )
)
```

The template looks like this:

```
<select>
    {{ #times }}
    <option value='{{hour}}{min}}'>{{time}}</option>
    {{ /times }}
</select>
```

No data is being inserted into the template. I've tried various combinations of `{{ . }}` and `{{ .hour }}`, etc inside the `{{ #times }}{{ /times }}` iterator. I've also tried using PHP’s `ArrayIterator` class, with no luck.

Comment: Should `{{hour}}{min}}` actually be `{{hour}}{{min}}` ?.

Comment: @BrettSantore You're correct, simple typo! Doesn't solve the issue however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax would be `{{#times}}` without spaces around and, as @BrettSantore noticed, one bracket is missing around `min`.

```
<select>
    {{#times}}
    <option value='{{hour}}{{min}}'>{{time}}</option>
    {{/times}}
</select>
```

Comment: This edit appears to have fixed your `value` attribute

Comment: Thank you! I'm a little surprised the Mustache tags are white-space sensitive... I thought surely the parser would account for any as long as the delimiters are there.

Comment: It was the missing brace, not the whitespace. You can totally use spaces around your tags — I always do. `{{ foo }}` == `{{foo}}`.

Comment: Ohh! I just noticed what you did. It *was* a whitespace issue. `{{ #foo }}` is definitely not the same thing as `{{# foo }}`. The second is the one you want :)

Comment: Bonus comment: if you want to more easily debug this, make sure caching is enabled in Mustache.php and check the compiled template class. It's pretty easy to follow, and you can see how Mustache interprets your template.